# Getting Inconsistent Sorting Results from MySQL Query on LIMIT changes

Tags: mysql, sql, pagination, codeigniter-2

My query (both below) return inconsistent sorting results as I increment pages (ex. LIMIT 3,3 to LIMIT 4,3). See the example image below and notice I have two new items despite only changing the FROM index by 1.

Worst of all, I cannot produce any particular sorting order consistently, except for the first set: LIMIT 0, 6. Then LIMIT 6,6 and other variations return wildly different results. For example, if i change the WANT value, i can get a completely different set of items.

**Example:**
http://trackauthoritymusic.com/wwwroot/images/pagination-error-proof.jpg

**Environment:**

- echo mysql_get_server_info(); // 5.1.67-log
- echo PHP_VERSION; // 5.4.14
- character_set_client == utf8
- character_set_connection == utf8
- character_set_database == utf8
- character_set_filesystem == binary
- character_set_results == utf8
- character_set_server == latin1
- character_set_system == utf8
- collation_connection == utf8_unicode_ci
- collation_database == utf8_unicode_ci
- collation_server == latin1_swedish_ci
- I am using codeigniter but i'm using standard sql seen below.
- On a shared hosting package

**Queries:**

```
SELECT S.*, G.* FROM games C LEFT JOIN songs T ON G.game_id = S.game_id WHERE G.game_status != 'deleted' and G.game_status != 'hidden' AND G.group_id = 1 GROUP BY G.game_id ORDER BY ISNULL(G.game_uploading_starts), G.game_listening_starts desc LIMIT 4, 3

SELECT S.*, G.* FROM games C LEFT JOIN songs T ON G.game_id = S.game_id WHERE G.game_status != 'deleted' and G.game_status != 'hidden' AND G.group_id = 1 GROUP BY G.game_id ORDER BY (CASE WHEN G.game_uploading_starts IS NULL then 1 ELSE 0 END), G.game_listening_starts desc LIMIT 4, 3
```

Both of these queries produce inconsistent sorting results, not simple different sets between the two of them.

**Queried Table Schema:**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `games`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `games` (
  `game_id` mediumint(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `group_id` mediumint(6) NOT NULL,
  `game_status` enum('playlist','game','compilation','halloffame','theme','deleted','hidden') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'hidden' COMMENT 'except deleted, this is not maintained at runtime, but on a cron job',
  `game_title` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `game_image` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `game_author_id` mediumint(6) NOT NULL,
  `game_ta_id` mediumint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `game_winner_id` mediumint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `song_id` mediumint(6) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'either first example or 1st place song if awarded already',
  `game_buyin` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `game_minpool` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `game_rating_avg` tinyint(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `game_songs_per_user` tinyint(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `game_uploading_starts` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `game_listening_starts` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `game_rating_starts` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `game_awarding_starts` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `game_uploading_ends` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `game_awarding_complete` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `game_created` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `game_summary` varchar(2000) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`game_id`),
  KEY `game_status` (`game_status`,`song_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=37 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `songs`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `songs` (
  `song_id` mediumint(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `game_id` mediumint(6) NOT NULL,
  `group_id` tinyint(3) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` mediumint(6) NOT NULL,
  `user_vendor_id` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `receipt_id` mediumint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `song_status` enum('example','game','playlist','compilation','deleted','winner') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'example',
  `song_title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `song_artist` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `song_album` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `song_released` smallint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `song_genre` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `song_location` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `song_reason` varchar(2500) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `song_image` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `song_rating_avg` smallint(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `song_adjusted_avg` decimal(5,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `song_rated_count` mediumint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `win_rating` smallint(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `song_timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `song_added` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `song_order` int(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `song_dedication` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`song_id`),
  KEY `game_id` (`game_id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  KEY `song_status` (`song_status`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=305 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume the problem is that you have multiple rows that have the same value for `G.game_listening_starts`.  These rows can be returned in any order, from one sort to the next.

What you want is a *stable* sort.  One where the ordering does not change.  To get a stable sort, you need for each row to be uniquely identified.  I might suggest:

```
ORDER BY ISNULL(G.game_uploading_starts), G.game_listening_starts desc, game_id
```

This is guaranteed to be unique because of the `group by`.

I happen to think that the [SQL Server documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx) does the best job of explaining stable sorts:

> To achieve stable results between query requests using OFFSET and
>   FETCH, the following conditions must be met:
>
> The underlying data that
>   is used by the query must not change. That is, either the rows touched
>   by the query are not updated or all requests for pages from the query
>   are executed in a single transaction using either snapshot or
>   serializable transaction isolation. For more information about these
>   transaction isolation levels, see SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL
>   (Transact-SQL).
>
> The ORDER BY clause contains a column or combination
>   of columns that are guaranteed to be unique.

I realize that you are using MySQL, but the same idea applies.